# Como contar valores consecutivos no Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Neste momento tenho esta formula que calcula valores consecutivos:

```
=SE(AB5=0;0;SE(OU(E(AB4>=100;AB5>=100);E(AB4<=-100;AB5<=-100));AC4+1;1))
```

Basicamente ela faz isto:

```
0           0
0           0
-110        1
-110        2
-110        3
-100        4
0           0
0           0
0           0
130         1
150         2
0           0
0           0
-100        1
0           0
0           0
0           0
0           0
-110        1
0           0
0           0
0           0
-220        1
-150        2
0           0
0           0
```

Mas eu pretendo que ela faça isto:

```
0           0
0           0
-110        0
-110        0
-110        0
-100        4
0           0
0           0
0           0
130         0
150         2
0           0
0           0
-100        1
0           0
0           0
0           0
0           0
-110        1
0           0
0           0
0           0
-220        0
-150        2
0           0
0           0
```

Ou isto:

```
0           0
0           0
-110        4
-110        0
-110        0
-100        0
0           0
0           0
0           0
130         2
150         0
0           0
0           0
-100        1
0           0
0           0
0           0
0           0
-110        1
0           0
0           0
0           0
-220        2
-150        0
0           0
0           0
```

Qual é a fórmula para tornar isto possível ?

Eu preferia não ter que adicionar mais colunas, pois o ficheiro já é grande...

Usar apenas uma fórmula para fazer este trabalho seria o melhor...

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Olá Fábio, esse é o site do Stackoverflow em português, traduza sua pergunta

Comment: Já traduzi a pergunta.

Comment: boa Fábio, senão ela pode ficar pendente por ser sinalizada como escrita em outra língua, agora está ok :)

Answer (score 1):

Para a fórmula não ficar muito extensa você pode usar outra coluna para comparar linhas, duas a duas, como a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Thiago, eu acho que vou por esta solução mesmo. Já tentei só com uma coluna e tudo resulta em formulas muito lentas. Obrigado, gashaste um upvote, pois embora não seja bem o que está na pergunta, a tua solução resolve o problema.